# Bienvenue “chez”, “sur”, “à”, or with another preposition?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

I have seen *bienvenue* followed by *à*, *sur*, and *chez*, and there may be others which I have not yet seen. When should each of these be used, and what other options are there, if any?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- **Chez**: used if followed by a noun owning the designated location (Bienvenue chez le coiffeur)
- **Sur**: used if you're on (sur) the location. Same goes for in (**dans** : Bienvenue dans la Matrice) and so on.
- **En**: used if the location is a region/country/etc with a feminine name *that is not an island* (Bienvenue en France *[LA France]*) or masculine name starting with a vowel or non-aspirated consonant (en Hollande)
- **À**: used if the location is:

  1. other regions/countries/etc with a masculine name (*will most likely be **au** in this case, I can't think of one where it is **à***) or islands (Bienvenue au Canada/à Madagascar)
  2. or a proper noun/a designation of a unique place (in the context of the current discussion) (Bienvenue à Paris/au restaurant dont je t'ai parlé)

Those are not academic rules, just my two cents.

---

*thanks to PapaPoule for the clarification on feminine/masculine names for regions/countries*

*thanks to Circeus for the clarification about island names*

Comment: You'll have *à* if the region/country is an island: *Bienvenue à la Martinique, Bienvenue à Madagascar, Bienvenue à Hawaii*

Comment: @Circeus That's right; yet it feels weird and too specific to be a rule... even though I can't describe it another way.

Comment: I don't know where the feminine masculine rule come from, but Canada is not an Island, and I would say "bienvenue en Corse" (la Corse=island), "bienvenue en Crète" (la Crète = island), and not "bienvenue à la Corse".

Comment: bienvenue à is also used when you say welcome to someone (bienvenue à vous !)

Comment: @radouxju Aren't these considered regions? I'm just trying to justify this arbitrary rule :p

Comment: @Kilazur Sorry, my comment was confusing : here is the rule : feminine -> EN , masculine starting with consonant ->  au, masculine starting with voyel -> EN, cities(or countries that are single cities, like Hong-Kong or Monaco) -> à, plural -> aux (e.g. aux Emirats Arabes Unis, aux Etats-Unis d'Amérique). Then there are exceptions for some, but not all, islands (Madagascar, Cuba, Chypre ..) and you should say "à Djibouti"

Comment: Hollande is not a masculine name...

Answer (score 4):

I would imagine it depends on where you are.

- Bienvenue chez moi. — Welcome to my house.
- Bienvenue sur Terre, sur le vol — Welcome to the flight (you're on the flight), welcome to earth (you're on earth)
- Bienvenue à Paris — Welcome to Paris.

Comment: So, does that mean it would be "Bienvenue en France"?

Comment: @Aerovistae, yes.